# Is there a hotkey for the crafting window?

Tags: rust

Often when I open the Inventory window with `Tab`, the crafting window is minimized and I have to click the `Crafting` button to open the window.

Is there a keyboard shortcut I can use to open the Crafting window?

Answer (score 1):

Meanwhile a lot has been restructured and a hotkey for the crafting view has been introduced.

With standard key bindings, just press <kbd>Q</kbd> to get directly to it and start crafting.